# c# object function calling

Tags: c#, oop, game-engine

So I am starting to learn c# and I am running into some problems... I am trying to create a bestiary for my console rpg game, and I have ran into a wall. In my monsters class, I have a class constructor for monster objects, and I have a function to print out the data in a bestiary style.

```
public void Mprint()
       {
           Console.WriteLine(name);
           Console.WriteLine("Class: " + mclass);
           Console.WriteLine("HP: " + healthmax);
           Console.WriteLine("Atk: " + atk);
           Console.WriteLine("Exp drop: " + expdrop);
           Console.WriteLine("Description: ");
           Console.WriteLine(description);
       }
```

then I have a void that is asking for your imput and then uses a switch statement to put you down the chain and eventually to your desired entry:

```
 switch (monsterchoice)
           {
               case 1:
                   rat.Mprint();
                   break;
               default:
                   Console.WriteLine();
                   Console.WriteLine("Make sure that you are using the number next to the name of the monster you choose.");
                   Console.ReadKey();
                   BestiaryBeast();
                   break;
           }
       }
```

Eventually you get to this chain which has the rat print function. Now my question is where do i define the rat to get the rat.Mprint to work here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way you have it should be fine, as long as rat has been declared and intialized as a 'Monster'. You need "var rat = new Monster()" either before the switch statement or inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Early days... this takes me back.

Assuming you are in a console application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Monster rat = new Monster("a", "b");
        List<Monster> monsters = new List<Monster> { rat };
        foreach (var monster in monsters)
        {
            monster.Mprint();
        }
    }
}
```

This will create a rat object and populate it.
it will add it to a monsters list
and then will print out the monsters.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As with any variable, you must declare it before you use it (your compiler will tell you if you forget this!). So this code is fine:

```
       Monster rat = null;
       switch (monsterchoice)
       {
           case 1:
               rat.Mprint();
               break;
           default:
               ...
       }
```

So is this:

```
       switch (monsterchoice)
       {
           case 1:
           {
               Monster rat = null;
               rat.Mprint();
               break;
           }
           default:
               ...
       }
```

The second is very unlikely to be what you *want* to do, as declaring your variable in each case statement is a bit odd, but it is valid. Now both of those will throw a `NullReferenceException` because you didn't set the variable to an actual object. So those lines should *actually* be:

```
Monster rat = new Rat(); //Or Monster, depending on your class design
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of advice; do not embed the consumer of a class (for example, the Console window) inside your classes. Your `Monster` class should look something like this:

```
public class Monster
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; set; }

    public string CharacterSheet
    {
        get
        {
            return Name + Environment.NewLine
                   + "HP: " + HitPoints;
        }
    }

    public Monster(string name, int hp)
    {
        Name = name;
        HitPoints = hp;
    }
}
```

Then you would print out your character sheet with code like:

```
Console.WriteLine(rat.CharacterSheet);
```